# Different terminal command line of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal

I am a beginner of python and Linux system.
I have installed python coverage and pytest module on my Macbook
But in terminal

```
python3-coverage report
pytest-3
```

doesn't work!!!

```
coverage report
pytest
```

works.
In our CSE lab, we always type the first command line.
Id like to know why is this happening.

Comment: Hi Matty, welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure that you have the same version of python installed on both machines? It looks like you may have Python3 on your CSE lab and Python2 on your local machine. Check by doing `python --version`

Comment: _doesn't work!!!_ What does that mean? Please be specific.

Comment: "have installed [things]" doesn't tell us *how* you installed something. Installing something with MacPorts is one thing; installing it with `pip` another (and has several variants, depending on whether you had a virtualenv active at the time, whether you used `--user`, whether you used `sudo`, etc). Details matter; for a conclusive answer to be provided, enough details to let someone else reproduce the same problem (and *know* that they've produced the same problem, vs the same symptoms via an unrelated mechanism) need to be included in the question itself.